# iphdr struct not found on mac

Tags: c++, macos, sockets, ip

i was trying to right some socket programming stuff and i faced the following error while trying to make the cpp files , i'm on OS X 10.11 :

user-router/sm.cpp:84:3: error: unknown type name 'iphdr'

here is the code for that specific section :

```
void SimulatedMachine::run () {
// TODO: write your business logic here...
struct ethernet_header {
byte  dst[6];
byte  src[6];
uint16 type;
} __attribute__ ((packed));

const int frameLength = sizeof (ethernet_header) + 100;
byte *data = new byte[frameLength];

ethernet_header *eth = (ethernet_header *) data;
memset (eth->dst, 255, 6); // broadcast address
memcpy (eth->src, iface[0].mac, 6);
eth->type = htons (0x0800);

iphdr *packet = (iphdr *) (data + sizeof (ethernet_header));
packet->version = 4;
packet->ihl = 5;
packet->tot_len = htons (100);

Frame frame (frameLength, data);
sendFrame (frame, 0); // sends frame on interface 0
delete[] data;
cerr << "now ./free.sh and check the pcap log file to see the sent packet" <<      endl;
}
```

as iphdr is supposed to exist in  i have that included as well.

any help is appreciated .

Comment: What on earth is `__attribute__ ((paenter code herecked))` supposed to do? None of those appear to be valid type attributes.

Comment: oops , thats __attribute__ ((packed)); mixed with stack overflow's "enter code here" hint. anyway as i mentioned the problem is with the iphdr struct, not the custom ethernet_header !